# Filter HTML messages by content

Tags: thunderbird, html, email-filter

I would like to filter the messages that contain some HTML content. I have tried to create a filter such as:

```
body contains ViewSettings.jspa?name=marius.botis">Marius Botis
```

I copied&pasted the string from the message source. Is this a bug or is it not intended to work this way? Any suggestions? :)

P.S.: I am using the latest thunderbird from Ubuntu (3.0.8)
P.S. 2: This is a sample of the html:

```
<tr style="vertical-align:top;">
  <td style="font-weight:bold;white-space:nowrap;">FromUser:</td>
  <td>
    <a href="http://server/ViewSettings.jspa?name=marius.botis">Marius Botis</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr style="vertical-align:top;">
  <td style="font-weight:bold;white-space:nowrap;">ToUser:</td>
  <td>
    <a href="http://server/ViewSettings.jspa?name=marius.botis">Marius Botis</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you add to your post a small example of the html?

Comment: Small example of HTML added

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (correct me if I am wrong) but thunderbird looks at the message content when you are filtering.  It does not look at the message source which would contain the html and plaintext portion of messages.

What specifically are you trying to filter?  I would imagine there is a way to do it without worrying about HTML source.

Comment: I would like to filter a HTML message received by thunderbird. The HTML contains the mentioned text. It is not possible to filter the message by sender, subject, etc. The only thing that signals me that some message is special is that it contains some information in its HTML. Anyway, it is obvious that the body part does not match, but in this case I'm not sure what the body represents for a HTML message.

Comment: The body represents the text, not the html markup to my knowledge.